# How to convert UTC timestamp in seconds to human readable local time in a shell script?

Tags: shell, date, converters, utc

Given UTC timestamp in seconds **1361322102.430** How do I convert it to human readable local time in a shell script?

Answer (score 3):

Same moment in time at **1361322102.430** UTC seconds

shown in local time zone

```
$ date -d @1361322102.430
Tue Feb 19 20:01:42 EST 2013
```

shown in UTC time zone

```
$ date -d @1361322102.430 -u
Wed Feb 20 01:01:42 UTC 2013
```

For more details → `$ info coreutils 'date invocation'`

Answer (score 1):

GNU:

```
$ date -d @1361414562.231
Wed Feb 20 18:42:42 PST 2013
```

Most BSDs:

```
$ date -r 1361414562.231
Wed Feb 20 18:41:38 PST 2013
```